# Ubuntu + SVN: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: svn

I have run through the below steps to create an SVN repository on Ubuntu:

1- `sudo apt-get install subversion apache2 libapache2-svn`

2- `sudo a2enmod ssl`

3- `sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl`

4- `sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key`

5- `sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf` and added this

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443
```

6- `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` and Comment out the default certificate and key:

```
#SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

and add:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
```

7- `sudo a2ensite default-ssl`

8 - `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

9- configure the SVN Server for this, make a directory where you want to keep the svn repositories and edit the dav_svn.conf file:

```
sudo mkdir /svn
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf
```

Delete all the data and make it simple like this:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
Require valid-user
SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

10- `sudo htpasswd -cm /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd myusername`

Type the new password.

11- `cd /svn`

```
sudo svnadmin create myrepo
```

12- `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /svn`

13- `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

When I open the URL: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/svn/myrepo

It asked for username and password --> success to login but it gave me this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="2">Could not open the requested SVN filesystem</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

any idea why am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: This error basically means that the `www-data` user is not able to access the SVN folder. One thing I note is that you are not setting `SVNPath`, but I am not sure that would be the cause.